# apache httpd-vhosts.conf who to redirect only socket.io calls from port 80

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, socket.io

I am not deep in the apache configuration so 
after ++hours of google and experiments and getting nervous I need help concering that all requests to my "site-name" using port 80 always end in redirection to node.js socket.io server script.

From browser I request index.htm which shall do the socket.io stuff.

How to configure httpd-vhosts.conf to allow calls to php/js/html/.. (except index.htm) to "site-name" using port 80 not to be redirected to node.js ?

(Xampp) Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30

httpd-vhosts.conf looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site-name

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8088/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass            http://localhost:8088/
ProxyPassReverse         http://localhost:8088/

</VirtualHost>
```

index.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Socket.io</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Communication with socket.io!</h1>

        <script src="http://site-name/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>     <script>
var socket = io();
console.log("socketId: " +  socket.id);

socket.on('news', function (data) {
console.log(data);
socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'client-data' });
});
```

Thank's for your help
Guido

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution by simply adding

```
# no proxy for php cgi-bin

ProxyPass           /php !

ProxyPass           /cgi-bin !
```